# What in my controller code is incorrect using group_by with the gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by

**Question:** How can I display the count for how many "orders" there are on a group_by basis (day, week, month)?

I am using the groupdate gem and can't see how I can take out the date information to only display the count or sum.  I need the sum of all of the counts added up.

**Controller**

```
@clients = User.all.where(affiliate_id: current_affiliate)
@orders_e = Order.all.where(seller: @clients ).where(order_status: [2] )
....
@orders_week = @orders_e.all.group_by { |week|  week.created_at.beginning_of_week }
....
@orders_month_2 = @orders_e.all.group_by_month(:created_at)
@orders_day_2 = @orders_h.all.group_by_day(:created_at, last: 1)
@orders_week_2 = @orders_h.all.group_by_day(:created_at, last: 7)
....
@orders_week_count = @orders_week.values.sum
```

**View:**

```
<%= @orders_month_2.count.sum() %>
```

**Output:** ["2018-12-01 00:00:00 UTC", 18]

When I do this for group_by_day, or group_by_week, it gives this:

```
[Tue, 11 Dec 2018, 0, Wed, 12 Dec 2018, 0, Thu, 13 Dec 2018, 0, Fri, 14 Dec 2018, 0, Sat, 15 Dec 2018, 0, Sun, 16 Dec 2018, 0, Mon, 17 Dec 2018, 0]
```

What I need is all of "0"'s added up.

**Alternative I have working as well:**

**view:**

```
<% @clients.each do |user| %>
  <h3 class="center"><%= user.sales.where(order_status: [2] ).group_by_month(:created_at).count.sum() %></h3>
<% end %>
```

**Output:** [Sat, 01 Dec 2018, 18]

I have done more attempt but I don't think listing all of them will help much as it will end up being way too much information.

How can I get back the information:

- Orders today
- Orders this week
- Orders this month

Comment: Firstly, are you talking about this gem - https://github.com/ankane/groupdate ? If yes - you have to update your question. 

To answer your question, try passing a `series` parameter to the `group_by_month` method and test again: `...group_by_month(:created_at, series: false).count`. I will post this as an answer if it is what you are searching for.

Comment: Yes thanks, thats what I mean, updated it.  "series: false" didn't end up working though.  The same problem with the date information showing up.  i tried just about everything on the gem git hub page.  I've tried a few other ways that gives me numbers with no dates but the numbers are never correct

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a simple way to remove the date info - the way i "solved" it was by creating a loop with a break so only one result appears.

```
<% @orders_day.each do |day, orders| %>
   <%= orders.count %>
   <% break if orders.first %>
<% end %>
```

It's in DESC order in the controller.

Although, this works for months as well, I couldn't get it to work correctly with weeks.  Maybe my internal computers clock was off but the daily would show 3, which is correct, but the weekly would show 1, which makes no sense.  Code is code so it's right somehow.

This isn't going to be an accepted response so if someone does have an answer for this questions, feel free to let me know because I will definitely want to hear how you can solve this question.